# Сделать проверку

Tags: sql

Есть числа, которые приходит в базу и я с помощью `SUM` суммирую их, получая общую сумму.

Числа приходят каждый месяц. Как сделать так, что бы показывались только сумма текущего месяца, т.е. сегодня 1.10.2016 и у меня сумма 100, завтра 2.10.2016 - сумма 350, а по достижению конца месяца вся сумма обнулялась и отсчет начинался заново? 
Это в модуле

```
 public function getOrder(){

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(Sum_back) AS Sum_back, name_sender, order_id FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` WHERE Sum_back > 0 GROUP BY name_sender");
    return $query->rows;
}
```

это контролер

```
 $senders = $this->model_module_limit->getOrder();
    print_r($senders);die();
    $this->data['senders'] = array();
    foreach ($senders as $sender){
        //$senders[] = "№–".$sender['order_id'];
        $this->data['senders'][] = array(
            'name_sender' => $sender['name_sender'],
            'Sum_back'    => ($sender['Sum_back']),
            'order_id'    => $sender['order_id']
        );
    }
```

это вюшка

```
 <?php  foreach($senders as $sender){ ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="left"><?php echo $sender['name_sender']; ?></td>
                    <td class="left"><?php echo (date("d.m.Y "));?></td>
                    <?php if($sender['Sum_back']){ ?>
                    <td class="left"><?php echo $sender['Sum_back']; ?></td>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <td class="left"><?php echo $massage?></td>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
```

Comment: "что бы показывались только сумма тетушкино месяца" - тут по конкретней пожалуйста

Comment: Приведите примеры кода, который вы используете. Что пытаетесь сделать? Что именно не получается?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/8ieb08fC код

Comment: @РоманЮшко вставьте код в свой вопрос, используя кнопку ["Править"](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/584987/edit).

Comment: И какая у вас БД. Функции для получения текущей даты (и месяца) во всех БД разные. А вообще вам надо добавить условие в запрос что дата больше или равна первому числу текущего месяца и возможно что меньше или равна последнему (если в БД могут быть записи "из будущего")